# Why I can't use command "revZipOpenArchive" with mobile(IOS) ? - livecode

Tags: livecode

I download file to my path.My path is "documents".

I test my code on runtime in pc.It's working.But when I test in emulator is not working and not error message.

Here code:

```
on mouseUp
   put specialFolderPath("documents") & "/testFile.zip" into pFile
   openArchive pFile
   revZipOpenArchive pFile, "read"
   --morecode zip file--
end mouseUp
```

Before command "revZipOpenArchive" is working.But after it's not working.

What do I do?

Comment: is it a typo - does pArchive have a value?  should it be revZipOpenArchive pFile, "read"  (instead of pArchive)

Comment: I'm sorry.I typed the wrong.It's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you don't get an error message in the emulator, because standalones don't display error messages by default and when you run a stack in an emulator, it runs as a standalone. If you want to display an error message, change your script to include a try control structure.

```
on mouseUp
   try
   put specialFolderPath("documents") & "/testFile.zip" into pFile
   openArchive pFile
   revZipOpenArchive pFile, "read"
   --morecode zip file--
   catch myErr
     answer error myErr
   end try
end mouseUp
```

I bet that LiveCode reports an error close to `573,5,4,revZipOpenArchive`, which in this example would mean that there is a problem at position 4 on line 5 of your script. The reason could be that you didn't include the ZIP external on the iOS pane of the Standalone Application Settings window. Note that including the ZIP external on the General pane of the Standalone Application Settings window won't do, because that's only for desktop standalones.

To display all errors, use this script:

```
on errorDialog theError
  beep
  answer error theError
end errorDialog
```

Comment: I don't check revZip in standalone application setting.Thank you Mark